# OpenXml SDK returns scientific values for large numbers

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm using the OpenXML SDK to parse .xlsx files.

When I have very large numbers in the Excel file, i.e. `344230125015305000`, OpenXML converts it to the scientific version, i.e. `3.4423012501530502E+17`. This is strange, as the "full" value is present in the Excel file, meaning it hasn't been truncated and it should be available somewhere in the [Cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell(v=office.15).aspx) object.

[image]

Any suggestions are most welcome.

UPDATE:

@AlexeiLevenkov suggested I look at the xml file, and it appears the values are stored in scientific form. Interestingly, Excel still shows the full form.

[image]

Examples:

```
344110425109461000 -> 3.4411042510946099E+17
344230125015305000 -> 3.4423012501530502E+17
344770124807291000 -> 3.4477012480729101E+17
344770224905172000 -> 3.4477022490517197E+17
```

Attempting to covert back to full form, i.e.

```
(long)Double.Parse("3.4411042510946099E+17", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

returns an incorrect value (`344110425109460992` for the above snippet).

Adding a single quote prefix to the value fixes the problem (another indicator, that the full form value is hidden in there somewhere), but it's not a solution for this scenario, as I'm try to build an automated processing of user-uploaded files.

Comment: Your scientific notation version has a **higher** precision than you're saying it reads in Excel?

Comment: As I understand, it has a lower precision? Attempting to convert it returns a different number, i.e. `(long)Double.Parse("3.4411042510946099E+17", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` is `344110425109460992`.

Comment: XML is text file... As first check open and look inside to see if there is indeed value you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good call, the value is stored in scientific form in the XML file. How do I convert it back to "full form"? Excel apparently knows how to...

Comment: I strongly suspect that the fact you see "...02" is artifact of formatting function used in Excel, not real precision. It just does no fit in normal double format used by both [C# `double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) and [Exce](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214118).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: Are you suggesting I should simply replace the ending "2E+17" with "00"?

Answer (score 3):

Use Open XML Productivity Tool and reflect the code of your file.
I did, here what the tool provides

```
public class GeneratedClass
{
    // Creates an Cell instance and adds its children.
    public Cell GenerateCell()
    {
        Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U };
        CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();
        cellValue1.Text = "3.4411042510946099E+17";

        cell1.Append(cellValue1);
        return cell1;
    }
}
```

So as you can see large numbers are store only in scientific notation, then you jus need

```
Double value = Double.Parse("3.4411042510946099E+17", 
   NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The value it will be ok!
The fun fact (Maybe some c# gurus can tell us why) is then you have to convert first to string.

```
String strdouble =  value.ToString("#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Int64 conv = Convert.ToInt64(value);
// conv will be: 344110425109460992
Int64 conv1 = Convert.ToInt64(strdouble, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// conv1 will be: 344110425109461000
```

Comment: The `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` flag was what I was looking for

Comment: The reason you need to convert to string first is because the value is too large to store in a Double or Int32 :)

Comment: That is not the point! The point is why converting a double to string gets you the right value while converting the same double to Int64 won't

Answer (score 0):

Your styles need to be declared like this:

```
 CellStyleFormats cellStyleFormats1 = new CellStyleFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
            CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)1U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyNumberFormat = true };
```

Notice the NumberFormatId and the ApplyNumberFormat, this ID must be one so that in the XML looks something like this:

```
<xf numFmtId="1" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>
```

PS:
From MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.numberingformat(v=office.14).aspx